# Проблема при создании базы SQL Server из C# (права на доступ к файлу)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net, sql-server

Ситуация такая, я создаю из приложения C# базу следующим кодом

```
CreateDB_SQL_command = "CREATE DATABASE " + "ExpData" + " ON PRIMARY " +
      "(NAME = Exp_Data_" + @DbName + ", " +
      @"FILENAME = '" + @DbFileName + "', " +
      "SIZE = 100MB, MAXSIZE = 10GB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
      "LOG ON (NAME = " + @DbLogName + ", " +
      @"FILENAME = '" + @DbLogFileName + "', " +
      "SIZE = 100MB, " +
      "MAXSIZE = 5GB, " +
      "FILEGROWTH = 15%)";

  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(CreateDB_SQL_command, myConn);
  try
  {
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

База создается, все хорошо, из ManagmenStudio отлично управляется, однако при попытке её открыть

```
switch (open_db_file.ShowDialog())
  {
    case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK:
      if (open_db_file.FileNames.Count() > 1)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("необходимо выбрать только 1 файл", "ошибка");
        return;
      }
      FilePath = open_db_file.FileName;
      break;
    case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel:
      return;
  }

  str_build = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
  str_build.DataSource = ".\\SQLEXPRESS";
  str_build.IntegratedSecurity = true;
  str_build.InitialCatalog = FilePath;
  str_build.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;


  using (ExpDataContext _db = new ExpDataContext(str_build.ToString()))
  {
    //.......
  }
```

При выборе файла в `OpenFileDialog` я получаю `MessageBox` который гласит, что у меня нет права доступа к этому файлу. Проблема лечится, если руками этому файлу прописать права доступа от текущего пользователя windows, через проводник. 
    Собственно вопрос, можно ли каким то образом так настроить SQL Server или так изменить скрипт создания базы, что бы текущий пользователь, да или хотя бы все имели право на доступ к .mdf файлу?
[Мануал](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms176061.asp) от msdn я прочитал, но ответа там не нашел.

Comment: Сам столкнулся с этим. До SQL Server 2012 проблем не было.

Comment: у меня он же стоит. SQL Server 2012 Express

Comment: Программно я эту проблему не решил. Заказчикам, в описании, предлагаю все сделать "ручками". Сейчас занят другим.
Буду Вам благодарен, если найдете решение.

Comment: друг посоветовал средствами winAPI при создании (после)     myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); менять права на доступ к файлу. Сейчас гуглю на конкретику, как напишу рабочий код - выложу в качестве ответа к вопросу

Comment: Это понятно. Меня смущает то, что до SQL Server 2012 проблем не было. И вообще,при очень малом опыте работы с этой версией, мне она не понравилась - не могу прямо открыть,созданные ранее на 2000 БД, отсутствие SQL-DMO и пр. Может это от лени? Я до недавнего времени, при малых объемах, предпочитал компактную MSDE. Особенно, если БД локальная. При работе с локальной, проблема получить имя SQL сервера. С трудом получил на Win7, а на Win8 этот код уже не работает...

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам вообще доступ к файлу базы данных (через проводник)? Приложение же работает с базой через SQL Server, все, что ему нужно знать - имя базы - `InitialCatalog`. Которое может не совпадать с именем файла!

Впишите InitialCatalog="master". Откройте соединение, и выполните запрос

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');
```

Результат - список всех не-системных баз - загрузите в комбобокс и покажите его пользователю. Выбранное пользователем значение подставьте как InitialCatalog в своем коде, вместо `FilePath`.